# Pass a Dictionary as a parameter to an NUnit parametrised test with TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to parametrise some tests and I've created an util class that contains a method which takes a Dictionary as a parameter. The util class looks roughly like this:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Car> GenerateCars(Dictionary<string, object> overwrite = null)
        {
            var Cars = new List<Car> {
            new Car
            {
                TopSpeed = 100,
                Brand = "Audi",
            },
            ...
            }

            if (overwrite != null)
            {
                foreach(var car in Cars)
                {
                // overwrite car top speed based on brand 
                }
            }

            yield return Cars;
        }
```

Now in my tests class I want to do something like this:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(CarFactory), "GenerateCars", methodParams: new object[] {null})] // works
[TestCaseSource(typeof(CarFactory), "GenerateCars", methodParams: new object[ new Dictionary<string, object> { {"Audi" : 50} }]] // err
```

The error I get is   `ValidationTests.cs(27, 13): [CS0182] An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type` which sounds like the `objects[]` array only accepts compile time constants. How could I pass that `Dictionary` as a compile time constant? I can't use enums as the `overwrite` logic is a bit more complicated and I've simplified it to be easier to understand.

Comment: you can't: a dictionary is surely nothing compiletime-constant. Maybe make your `GenerateCars`-function accepting two arrays? Anyway: why does your testcaseprovider itself need params?

Comment: Good point, maybe I should move that custom dictonary inside the testcaseprovider method.